# Not able to reset fields in apex

Tags: oracle-apex, apex

I have an apex screen where i have emp name field browse file field and upload button.
Now my requirement is that when user try to upload files on those days he should get notification that cannot upload file. For that I have written dynamic action on browse field item. Now part two is that after notification I need to clear/ reset browse file field. I tried to user apex set value but it is not working on browse file field but when I try to use same in emplane field it works. How can I reset file browse field. Any suggestions

I am able to clear values of browse file field but it in dev mode it shows there are some java errors any idea

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest slightly different approach.

Create two regions on page: the one you already have, and another which will be used to display a message.

- both regions will be "Static content" ones
- region (let's call it "upload") contains file browse item and button
- region (let's call it "message") doesn't contain anything; its HTML source code says "Upload can not be performed on weekends."

Create server-side conditions (type: function body) for both regions; they will be opposite:

- region "upload":

  ```
  return to_char(sysdate, 'DY', 'nls_date_language = english') NOT in ('SAT', 'SUN');
  ```
- region "message":

  ```
  return to_char(sysdate, 'DY', 'nls_date_language = english')     in ('SAT', 'SUN');
  ```

Run the page; if you do that between Monday and Friday, you'll be able to upload file. For example, today is Wednesday and form looks like left hand side of the screenshot. On Saturday and Sunday, it looks like the right hand side:

[image]

Therefore, you don't have to write dynamic actions, worry about clearing/resetting items ... you simply wouldn't display them.